# Iterate over a YAML object using Jinja template

Tags: yaml, jinja2

I have a yaml file with the following contents in it

```
interfaces:
   'loopback:local':
        -address: 0.0.0.0
         prefix: 24
         area: 192.168.1.2
         grp: testint
         intname: global
        -address: 0.0.0.0
         prefix: 24
         area: 192.168.1.3
         grp: prodint
         intname: global2
```

My jinja template looks like this

```
{% for intf in interfaces %}
  {{ intf }}

  {% for key,value in intf.items() %}
       {{ key }}
       {{ value }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

When I try to access the elements from the object, I get an error saying no elements found

Comment: Please show us the code you're using to render this template.

Comment: I did paste the contents of my jinja template.

Comment: Your YAML is invalid to start with: `-address: 0.0.0.0` misses a spaces between the dash and the key.

Comment: "I did paste the contents of my jinja template." That's not what I asked for. We need to see the code you're using to render this template -- either the Python code, or the Ansible playbook, etc, so we know how you're reading the YAML and how you are passing values to the template.

Comment: I am not using this code as part of a Ansible playbook or  Python code. This will be passed to a different tool.

Answer (score 0):

More likely you shoud try something like this:

**vars**:

```
interfaces:
  - loopback_local:
    - address: 0.0.0.0
      prefix: 24
      area: 192.168.1.2
      grp: testint
      intname: global
    - address: 0.0.0.0
      prefix: 24
      area: 192.168.1.3
      grp: prodint
      intname: global2
```

**jinjafile**

```
{% for intf in interfaces %}
  {% for i in intf.loopback_local %}
    {% for key,value in i.items() %}
       {{ key }}:{{ value }}
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```